When does a vector belong to the cone determined by other vectors?
I trying to find a simple condition to decide if a vector $w \in \mathbb{R}^3$ belongs to the cone determined by other vectors $v_1,v_2,v_3 \in \mathbb{R}^3$. That is, how can I find whether $w \in \{a_1 v_1 + a_2 v_2 + a_3 v_3 \colon a_1 \geq 0, a_2 \geq 0, a_3 \geq 0\}$?

I can't guess what simple means to you, but I also can't think of anything simpler than this. Break the problem into various cases depending on the linear independence properties of the vectors $v_1,v_2,v_3$.
Case 3: Suppose the three of $v_1,v_2,v_3$ are linearly independent. Use linear algebra to find the unique $a_1,a_2,a_3$ such that $w=a_1v_1+a_2v_2+a_3v_3$, and inspect $a_1,a_2,a_3$ to see if they are all $\ge 0$.
Case 2: Suppose only two of them are linearly independent, and let's say that you have a linear dependency equation amongst them of the form $b_1v_1 + b_2 v_2 + b_3 v_3 = 0$. Using this, you can determine whether one of $v_1,v_2,v_3$ is in the cone of the other two, and now there are two subcases.
Suppose one of them, let's say $v_3$, is in the cone of the other two. Now you just need to determine whether $w$ is in the cone of $v_1$ and $v_2$. Use linear algebra to determine whether $w$ is in the span of $v_1,v_2$, and if so just examine the coefficients.
Otherwise, if no one of $v_1,v_2,v_3$ is in the cone of the other two, you prove a little lemma saying that the cone of $v_1,v_2,v_3$ is equal to the span of any two of them. And now, again, you just need to determine whether $w$ is in the linear span of $v_1,v_2$.
Case 1: If only one of $v_1,v_2,v_3$ is linearly independent then their span is a line, and it's like the previous case only easier.
Case 0: And in the last case where $v_1=v_2=v_3=(0,0,0)$, well, that's easy too.
